# where is _Decorated suffix in ::class names from?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am learning gradle + Kotlin DSL by trying to understand all the "magic" objects (implicit receivers) it creates:

```
// hello, world build.gradle.kts

tasks.register("hello") {
    doLast {
        println("Hello world! ${tasks::class} ${this::class}")
    }
}
```

I am curious what is the object class of the (predefined)`tasks` container or the `Task`that is implicitly created (receiver of `doLast` I guess?); I get:

```
Hello world! class org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer_Decorated class org.gradle.api.DefaultTask_Decorated
```

I shouldn't be surprised by the `*.internal` class name but where is `DefaultTask_Decorated` from? The public api lists `*.api.DefaultTask` only.

Answer (score 0):

org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer_Decorated looks to be the internal TaskContainer implementation. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskContainer.html in particular "You can obtain a TaskContainer instance by calling Project.getTasks(), or using the tasks property".